# Stopping C# Windows service TimerCallBack

Tags: c#-4.0

My requirement here , a windows service needs to run every 50 seconds on the server.
For that Am using below code in Onstart() method

```
 private Timer stateTimer;
 private TimerCallback timerDelegate;

 timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(StartService);
 stateTimer = new Timer(timerDelegate, null, 0, 50/0.01);
```

here StartService is my method name which is being called in every 50 seconds

So now the service is running every 50 seconds,It's fine.
Now what code should i write to stop this execution in OnStop() method
To completely stop.Help needed urgently please.

Comment: Windows Service is stopped by calling the `Stop()` method. Use this in your timer callback method when the conditions for stopping the service are fulfilled.

Comment: HI Anders,Can you elaborate more than this, I tried using this codestateTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);  But when i implement this code in OnStop,error is throwing as object reference not set to object.How can i refer the same object which is being referd in OnStart Method

Comment: Do you mean that you only would like to stop the timer from "ticking", you do not want to stop the service altogether? In that case, how would you resume the timer "ticks"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, I assume that you are mainly interested in accessing the `Timer` object in the callback method. If this is what you want, you should use the [one-argument Timer constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149618.aspx), because this constructor will set the `state` variable that is passed to the callback method to the `Timer` object itself.

Hence, you should initialize your timer and set the `dueTime` and `period` like this:

```
stateTimer = new Timer(timerDelegate);
stateTimer.Change(0, 50000);  // for an interval of 50 seconds
```

Then, in your timer callback method, you can access the `Timer` object like this:

```
void StartService(object state) {
    var myTimer = (Timer)state;
    ...
}
```

Now, if you use this approach to stop the timer from ticking, e.g. by calling `myTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)` in `StartService`, the timer callback will no longer be called. Unless there is some other thread running simultaneously, the service will then be idling indefinitely, or at least until the service is manually stopped or the system restarted. In my view, it would be better to call the [ServiceBase.Stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.stop.aspx) method directly instead of stopping the timer from ticking.